# WPF printing looks like newspaper columns

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

**Background**

I am having a bit of trouble printing with WPF. Let's say that I have a flow-control document that looks as follows.

*My first page looks like this:*

```
-- Page 1 --     
1
2    
3    
4    
5
```

*My second page looks something like this:*

```
-- Page 2 --
6    
7    
8    
9    
10
```

So, to make this more clear, here is what the contents of my flow-document actually look like:

```
-- Page 1 --     
1
2    
3    
4    
5

-- Page 2 --
6    
7    
8    
9    
10
```

Well, when I go and print. This is what the output looks like (on the 8.5x11 paper), or in other words I will get all of the following, *being printed on a single page from left to right.* The output is doing it like a newspaper when in fact all of my document items are just runs are simply sequential. So like... all of the following will appear on a single page.

```
-- Page 1 --     -- Page 2 --  
1                6    
2                7    
3                8    
4                9    
5                10
```

Here is my source code for printing:

```
private void button_Print_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IDocumentPaginatorSource s = null;
    FlowDocument fd = null;
    PrintDialog p = new PrintDialog();

    // specify the document
    fd = this.richTextBox_Contents.Document;
    s = fd;

    // print the document
    if (p.ShowDialog().Value == true)
    {
        p.PrintDocument(s.DocumentPaginator, "Contents");
    }
}
```

**Question**

So is there any way to stop this document from returning to new columns as it's being printed? And just print everything straight from top to bottom?

Comment: @Adam, exact duplicate. Should I remove the question?

Comment: You could close your question I believe as having a dup

Comment: @Adam Ok, I've voted. Don't know what that's going to do.

Comment: @Adam nevermind, figured it out.